# Where to edit XML for "Lookup Filter" in Force.com

Tags: ide, metadata-api, metadata, lookup, xml

I created custom lookup fields for my custom object in web UI. Some of these lookup fields have lookup field filters. I need to create the same filter for many other similar lookup fields. I downloaded the custom object to Force.com IDE. I have access to these lookup fields, but I can not find meta data (xml) for the lookup filter. Where should I look ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`The namedFilter appears as a child of the target object of the associated lookup field.`

Source : https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/namedfilter.htm

Basically you need to look in the metadata of the target custom object on the lookup field. Hope this helps.